# How can I prevent a node from being cropped in an axis environment?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to put labels on the left side of a y-axis, but the text gets cropped. How can I prevent this?

[image]

(Also, the entries are looking awful, so any ideas how to make it looking better are greatly appreciated. I want to recreate this: [How do I generate a logarithmic x-axis without a y-axis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98695/how-do-i-generate-a-logarithmic-x-axis-without-a-y-axis))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=12cm,
    y=2cm,            % y unit vector
    hide y axis,        % hide the y axis
    xmode = log,        % logarithmic x axis
    axis x line*=bottom,% only show the bottom x axis line, without an arrow tip
    xmin=1e-4, xmax=1e2,% range for the x axis
    xlabel = Dose in Sv,
    every x tick/.style={black, line width=0.3pt}
]
\addplot [no markers, line width=8pt] table {
0.002 1
0.004 1
};

\node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:2e-4,1) {Hello};

\addplot [no markers, line width=8pt] table {
60 2
100 2
};

\node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:2e-4,1) {Hello};
\node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:2e-4,2) {Is it me you're looking for?};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add `clip=false` to your `axis` options, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13281/declare-nodes-in-pgfplots-as-overlays. For making it look better: I'd probably use `ymin=0, y=3ex` in the axis options to make sure the bars are always spaced the same distance apart, regardless of the number of lines you have. If you specify the line widths using the same units (e.g. `line width=2.5ex`), you can control whether you want a small gap between the bars.

Comment: @Jake Could you make that an answer?

Comment: @biologue: Did that work? Or did you end up using something else (in that case, could you post an answer)?

Comment: Frankly, I don't remember. I ended up not using this plot, sorry.